# initialising structs and passing by reference

Tags: c, struct, flexible-array-member

I'm fairly new to C and I am having trouble working with structs. I have the following code:

```
typedef struct uint8array {
 uint8 len;
 uint8 data[];
} uint8array;

int compare_uint8array(uint8array* arr1, uint8array* arr2) {
  printf("%i %i\n data: %i, %i\n", arr1->len, arr2->len, arr1->data[0], arr2->data[0]);
  if (arr1->len != arr2->len) return 1;
  return 0;
  }

int compuint8ArrayTest() {
 printf("--compuint8ArrayTest--\n");
 uint8array arr1;
 arr1.len = 2;
 arr1.data[0] = 3;
 arr1.data[1] = 5;    

 uint8array arr2;
 arr2.len = 4;
 arr2.data[0] = 3;
 arr2.data[1] = 5;    
 arr2.data[2] = 7;    
 arr2.data[3] = 1;    

 assert(compare_uint8array(&arr1, &arr2) != 0);
}
```

Now the output of this program is:

```
 --compuint8ArrayTest--
 3 4
 data: 5, 3
```

Why are the values not what I initialized them to? What am I missing here?

Comment: C doesn't have pass-by-reference. What you're doing in the code you show us is simply passing pointers.

Comment: You did not allocate any memory for the `data` array, so `arr1.data[0]` writes out of bounds (causing undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, `uint8 data[];` is a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). You need to allocate memory to `data` before you can actually access it.

In your code, you're trying to access invalid memory location, causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.2.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. Howev er, when a . (or ->) operator has a left operand that is
>   (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that
>   member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the
>   offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ
>   from that of the replacement array. **If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if
>   it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that
>   element or to generate a pointer one past it.**

A proper usage example can also be found in chapter §6.7.2.1

> EXAMPLE 2 After the declaration:
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure `struct s` has a flexible array member `d`. A typical way to use this is:
>
> ```
> int m = /* some value */;
> struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to `malloc` succeeds, the object pointed to by `p` behaves, for most purposes, as if
>   `p` had been declared as:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```